# Refactor Ant scripts - multiple directories

Tags: ant, refactoring, build

I have a set of databases that are built using scripts that are run using Ant.
I have the scripts for each database in a separate directory.

```
root (build.xml)
 - db1 (build.xml, *.sql)
 - db2 (build.xml, *.sql)
...
```

The root build.xml has a target

```
<target name="all">
 <ant dir="db1"/>
 <ant dir="db2"/>
 ...
</target>
```

The build.xml in each of the subfolders is essentially the same but for the database name.

Is there a way to refactor this to one single build file that runs the sql scripts in each of the folders against the corresponding databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `subant` task. The [examples in the docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) show how it can be used to iteratively invoke Ant builds in subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Depends very much on what's in your build files. In general, <for> or <foreach> might help you to iterate over the sub-folders and apply a piece of script to each of them.